# Is it possible to write to multiple socket connections at the same time in python?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I have a requirement where I want to to multiple socket connections at the same time. The data that need to be sent is the same. I can do it in a for loop like this:

```
def senToConn(sockList):
    for eachConn in sockList:
        eachConn.send("same data")
```

But is there a way that I can simultaneously write to all the connections at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not -- in python or any other language.

Each of those connections is via a separate socket, each of which is represented by a separate file descriptor. There is no system call that allows one to write data (whether the same or different) to multiple file descriptors in one fell swoop. Your `for` loop is the best approach.

Comment: If I am using pipes between processes will it be similar to sockets? I mean will it be given a file descriptor?

Comment: Yes. Pipes are also implemented via file descriptors, and will be subject to the same limitation.

Comment: Does Windows and Linux handle pipes differently or they are the same?

Comment: System call details are significantly different, but the concepts are similar enough that a library emulation layer can give the same behavior.

Comment: I am using asynchronous programming using python. In `Linux` if I am using the same code and I am waiting for the file descriptor to become readable and it is working good. But if I use the same code in `Windows` its throwing me `OS` error. Does the behavior dependent on the programming language also?

Comment: That sounds like it might be another question (and I'm probably not going to be able to help with Windows anyway). If you do ask another question, the details that go along with the `OSError` exception will be important as those details identify exactly what went wrong at the system call level. Also, you will need to explain exactly which async features you're using and how you're using them.